# Adding custom group provider to Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

How to add a custom group provider to Keycloak (Keycloak 16.1.1 or lower)? I can add a custom user provider (using an extension) without any problem and I see it in User Federation section (in drop-down menu) in the admin console, but I can't get the group provider even after deploying (both artifacts exist in 'keycloak-16.1.1\standalone\deployments' folder).

User extension: file META-INF/services/org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory with the path to custom user provider factory. Works fine.

Group extension: file META-INF/services/org.keycloak.storage.group.GroupStorageProviderFactory with the path to custom group provider factory. This deployed extension doesn't appear in User Federation section.

I've tried using UserGroupMembershipFederatedStorage instead of GroupStorageProviderFactory.